Can a Redis Cluster slave become a master when another master-slave pair completely fails?
So let's say I've got masters A, B, C. And they have slaves - A1, B1, C1 respectively.
If C-C1 master-slave pair completely fails, is there a way to have one of the other slaves (let's say B1) wipe themself from data and become a fresh master (C) automatically?
So when the old C-C1 nodes rejoin, they would become slaves themselves (B1, C1).


is there a way to have one of the other slaves (let's say B1) wipe themself from data and become a fresh master (C) automatically?

No.
Also, if C (the primary) and C1 (its only replica) fail, and they covered at least one hash slot, the entire cluster would be down by default. You can change this behavior by setting the cluster-require-full-coverage option to no in your configuration file.
https://redis.io/docs/latest/operate/oss_and_stack/management/scaling/
